# Sending an SMS Message

Tags: sms

how i can send sms from asp.net?any idea about it?or any resource through which i can get any information

Comment: @EMy you have to have an sms provider for doing so....  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/548911/sending-sms

Comment: @Emy search for `sms` tags in stackoverflow...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use SMS Global, although it's an Australian company. They provide a nice set of APIs and have examples for ASP .Net. http://www.smsglobal.com/en-au/technology/developers.php

Answer (score 0):

This API is good. It can solve my communication problem:https://www.globalsms.cn/Api_en/